# R Programming : Logical dataframe to actual dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I need to convert or manipulate the records based on the logical dataframe in R.
 I want to match with original dataframe and populate only those values equal to true from original dataframe and null for false value and also maintain the dataframe structure as well. Please suggest

For eg :

Original dataframe

```
ID Name Title
1 John Mr
2 Mike Mr
3 Susan Dr
```

Logical Dataframe

```
ID Name Title
False False False 
False True False 
False False True
```

Expected Dataframe

```
ID Name Title
2 Mike <null>
3 <null> Dr
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Your output does not make sense in any language and/or table subsetting, without more constraints and/or process. For instance, is there a reason the first row is missing? Another point, `data.frame` does not store `NULL` in cells. Just try `mtcars[2,2] <- NULL`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Jeroen.Just to be more specific , I compared two dataframes in R and arrive at the logical matrix and I am trying to find the mismatch values which equals to true in dataframe and need to dummy all the other variables as either null or NA or blank space. Need to keep ID as it is the primary key and first row I want to neglect since it doesnt have any True values in it.

Comment: BTW, Dinesh, I suspect Jeroen's comment was more a hint to *"show the code you have tried"*. Many questions can come across as *"code this for me, here are my needs"*, we often stress that SO is not a "free-code-service". By showing code you've tried, we can often give answers that are more specific to your needs (and perhaps style), and potentially advise on errors or faults you have in your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shot:

```
orig <- read.table(text="ID Name Title
1 John Mr
2 Mike Mr
3 Susan Dr", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
lgl <- read.table(text="ID Name Title
False False False 
False True False 
False False True", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

newdf <- mapply(function(d,l) { d[!l] <- NA; d; }, orig, lgl)
newdf
#      ID Name   Title
# [1,] NA NA     NA   
# [2,] NA "Mike" NA   
# [3,] NA NA     "Dr" 
newdf[ rowSums(!is.na(newdf)) > 0, ]
#      ID Name   Title
# [1,] NA "Mike" NA   
# [2,] NA NA     "Dr"
```

Your expected output is inconsistent in that you have `FALSE` in your `$ID` column, but you keep them in your output. You can fix that by changing those to `TRUE` and changing the filter to `rowSums(!is.na(newdf)) > 1`.

**Explanation**:

- `mapply` runs a function (named or anonymous) on one or more lists, like a "zipper" function. That is:

  ```
  mapply(func, 1:3, 4:6, 7:9, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
  ```

  is equivalent to

  ```
  list(func(1,4,7), func(2,5,8), func(3,6,9))
  ```
- `!is.na(newdf)` creates a data.frame of the same dimensions/names, but all elements are `logical`.
- since in general `sum(<logical_vector>)` returns a single integer of how many elements are true, `rowSums(...)` returns a vector, one element per row, where each element is the number of "trues" on that row.
- `... > 0` returns a logical vector, only passing the rows that have at least one non-`NA` element.

You said you wanted to always preserve `$ID`. In that case, you probably want to do (before process):

```
lgl$ID <- TRUE
```

and change the condition to `... > 1` to me *"at least two non-`NA` elements, one of which we know is `ID`"*.

Comment: That solves the purpose with some modification. I modified the logical dataframe into proper dataframe by lgl <- data.frame(lgl) and then used it and it worked. Great :) But still trying to understand the logic :P

Comment: Further explanation added. If this answers your question, please "accept" it by selecting the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Comment: I'm curious, Dinesh, why did you unaccept the answer?